# Best way to tunnel RMI over HTTP

Tags: java, sockets, rmi, java-web-start

I'm looking for a secure way to tunnel RMI traffic.
In My application(java Webstart) i must assume that the only port that is open is port 80.

I have the looked att socketfactories for rmi but do i really need a proxy then.

I need to do all my tunneling on the client side.
The only firewall i am trying to get past is on the client side.
I'm not able to open 1099 with port ranges above.
Would be nice to see some implementations.
Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you ask the client-side netadmins what security is to be gained in closing outbound ports, and get them to make an exception for port 1099, which was reserved for RMI at IANA in about 1995.

Comment: But even if thats possible, RMI uses random ports after that?
How to specify that RMI only should use 1099?

Comment: Have you considered Spring's HTTPInvoker (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#remoting-httpinvoker). It's very easy to use, goes over port 80, and lets you program in an RMI style against interfaces.

Comment: Okey, i've reach this:
I need to create a java proxy for RMI locally and then use a TunnelSocketFactory to use my proxy. This proxy should run beside the RMI application on the client side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Port 1099 was reserved for RMI at IANA in about 1995. There is no reason for it not to be open for outbound access in the client-side firewall.

RMI can be made to use fixed port numbers by supplying a port number when constructing (`super(port)`) or exporting (`exportObject(object, port)`). Better still, if you create the Registry within the server JVM via `LocateRegistry.createRegistry()`, all subequently exported remote objects will use that port unless they specify a different port or they use a server socket factory.

BUT ... RMI already includes HTTP tunneling 'out of the box'. No external solution required. You have to deploy the RMI-Servlet provided with the JDK, at the server end.

Comment: Boy, I wish this answer had been here 3 years ago when I had the same problem.

Comment: Thank you! This solves it if my network guys want to open any port.
So it still come back to a solution to tunnel my traffic over HTTP.
And if anyone have a java based http proxy laying around? :D
I'm trying to make it work with a tunnelsocket that creates a socket with a specified proxy. This tunnelsocket should direct all my traffic over http via the proxy i hope...

Comment: Eh? You don't need it. Just get them to open port 1099 and adjust your server code as above.

Comment: It's a hospital, so no i can't.

Comment: hmmm... I'm trying to find the RMI-Servlet that should be provided with the JDK but I'm coming up empty. Can you give me a link to some documentation on this?

Comment: "Better still, if you create the Registry within the server JVM via LocateRegistry.createRegistry(), all subequently exported remote objects will use that port unless they specify a different port or they use a server socket factory."  this is not true. The port selection for socket communication is still random and is not related to what you specify during registry creation.

Answer (score 0):

(a)
although not the newest fashion, exposing remote services with Hessian and Burlap seems to be a simple solution to avoid problem working across firewalls: http://hessian.caucho.com/doc/

see sample code for the server and client side:
http://www.javatpoint.com/spring-remoting-by-hessian-example

(b) or consider using Spring HttpInvokder (see some sample code here: http://www.javatpoint.com/spring-remoting-by-http-invoker-example)

HttpInvokder provides more customization options through the RemoteInvocationFactory, RemoteInvocationExecutor and HttpInvokerRequestExecutor strategies (for example, to add custom context information (such as user credentials) to the remote invocation, or using java’s built-in object serialization etc.), see:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/remoting/support/RemoteInvocationFactory.html